# Why did this character simply die in Deadgirl (2008)?

Tags: plot-explanation, deadgirl

In the film [Deadgirl (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0896534/), after jock boyfriend Johnny is bitten in his privates by the dead girl, he gets sick for a few days and later dies by excreting his own intestines.

After this happens, JT finds out that if the dead girl bites you, you will turn into a zombie too. He finds this out after she bites Dwyer.

So if this is true, then why didn't Johnny turn into a zombie instead of simply dying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He didn't simply die, he turned into a deadboy. Note that he was *crawling* along the ground with his intestines hanging out (not the usual behaviour you'd expect from someone who has suffered the sort of fatal intestinal prolapse you'd associate with the very last stages of Ebola), then we find this dialogue later in the film...

> **Dwyer:** *Johnny's got his guts stuck back into him and he's starting to smell
> like fucking rotten meat, okay?*
>
> ...
>
> **JT:** *But now I know, one bite from her and I can make another.*

The only way he could know that is if Johnny hadn't just died but had, in fact
turned into a <s>zombie</s> deadperson

Comment: FWIW, the word "simply" was added as an edit by another user. I realize there was nothing simple about his death but I did remember something said about him being dead after the whole disembowelment. Also I was under the impression that the whole "now I know, one bite from her" dialogue came after killing Dwyer, not Johnny.

Comment: @sanpaco - The quote is "He's dead...She's dead". Basically they've come to the realisation that deadpeople are in fact undead.

Comment: Just watched again and paid closer attention. According to Dwyer, Johnny is in the hospital and starting to smell like rotten meat. This is when JT makes the connection that one bite from her and you become like her. FWIW, your first line in your answer is spoken by Dwyer, not JT.